# Determining which Selenium Test Case Threw a SeleniumCommandTimedOutException

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

I have a large selenium test suite which I developed and tested with Selenium IDE in firefox. I just ran the test suite through Selenium Server against Internet Explorer. All of the tests pass in firefox, but IE crashes in the middle of running the test suite and I don't know which test case causes the crash. On the command line, I get the following exception:

```
15:35:28.000 INFO - Checking Resource aliases HTML suite exception seen:
at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumCommandTimedOutException
at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.runHTMLSuite(HTMLLauncher.java:130)
at org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.runHTMLSuite(HTMLLauncher.java:166)
at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.runHtmlSuite(SeleniumServer.java:555)
at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.boot(SeleniumServer.java:248)
at org.openqa.selenium.server.SeleniumServer.main(SeleniumServer.java:208)
16:05:21.659 INFO - Shutting down...
```

My Selenium results.html file is empty with no additional debugging clues. How do I determine which test case caused the problem? Is there a debug option that I could enable?

Here is the command which I use to run the test suite:

```
java –jar selenium-server.jar –htmlsuite *iexplore http://mysite.com C:\path\to\testsuite.html c:\path\to\result.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how you can run the RC with logging turned on:

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -log someLogFileName.log
```

You can also have browser side logs:

```
java -jar selenium-server.jar -browserSideLog
```

You can also combine the two.

For more info, go [to this site](http://wiki.openqa.org/display/SRC/Selenium+RC+Logging).

Answer (score 0):

set -timeout to a large number.